# Sequelize with asynchronous configuration in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, sequelize.js

I have been bashing my head for days as I cannot find a valid example of async configuration in Sequelize

So as you may know, you can simply config a Sequelize instance like that

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://user:pass@example.com:5432/dbname')
```

and then declare your Model

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    // allowNull defaults to true
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
});
```

However what happens when the db credentials comes from an external service?

```js
const credentials = await getDbCredentials();
const sequelize = new Sequelize({credentials})
```

since sequelize models creation are coupled with the instance creation (unlike many others ORMs) this becomes a big problem.

My current solution is the following:

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

// Models
const { User } = require("./User");

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const db = {};

let sequelize = null;

const initSequelize = async () => {
  if (!sequelize) {
      let configWithCredentials = {};

      if (env === "production") {
        const credentials = await getDbCredentials();
        const { password, username, dbname, engine, host, port } = credentials;
        configWithCredentials = {
          username,
          password,
          database: dbname,
          host,
          port,
          dialect: engine,
          operatorsAliases: 0
        };
      }

      const config = {
        development: {
          // Dev config 
        },
        production: configWithCredentials,
      };

      sequelize = new Sequelize(config[env]);

      sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
         console.log("db authenticated")
        });
      });
  }

  db.User = User;

  db.sequelize = sequelize;
  db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
};

initSequelize().then(() => {
  console.log("done");
});

module.exports = db;
```

However I feel that this is not a good approach because of the asynchronous nature of the initialization and sometimes the `db` is undefined.
Is there a better way to approach this thing?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this with beforeConnect hook, something like this:

```
sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, '', '', config);
sequelize.beforeConnect(async (config) => {
    config.username = await getSecretUsername();
    config.password = await getSecretPassword();
});
```

Leave the initial credentials empty, then use beforeConnect to mutate the config. Not sure if this is the cleanest way to use it but seems to be working.

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html

Comment: i think this should be the accepted answer now. the documentation explicitly says this "These hooks can be useful if you need to asynchronously obtain database credentials, or need to directly access the low-level database connection after it has been created."

Answer (score 2):

I think your db is sometimes undefined, because in your async function you're not "waiting" for the resolution of sequelize.authenticate(). Change this:

```
sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
         console.log("db authenticated")
        });
```

To this:

```
 await sequelize.authenticate()

 console.log("db authenticated")
```

What was happening, is that your  initSequelize async function would resolve, before sequelize.authenticate promise would. This is a common pitfall in JS. I think this adjustment will solve your problem. Regarding "the best approach", i don't see much that can be done here, but of course i don't have the entire picture.

Comment: But the async function keeps running

Comment: Oh i see what your getting at... `.authenticate()` isn't required to setup a sequelize connection.

Comment: It does initiate a connection to test it, but an app will be able to use the DB without it.

Comment: Wait..but was i right or wrong about the "then" issue? Let's put aside the sequelize stuff, there is a very fundamental thing here which i have to understand :D You have a very high score and i trust you :D

Comment: What you pointed out is correct, sorry! :)  The async function wasn't waiting for that promise to complete.  It just happens not to impact anything in this instance.

Comment: actually the databse gets authenticated correctly, is the db object and the entities that do not get populated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a 'pure' sequelize way to do this through lifecycle [hooks](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#connection-hooks):

Basically a generic setup in a db.js file would look like this:

```js
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const asyncFetch = require('../util/async-fetch');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'mysql',
  database: 'db_name',
  host: '127.0.0.1'
});

sequelize.beforeConnect(async (config) => {
  const [username, password] = await Promise.all([
    asyncFetch('username'),
    asyncFetch('password')
  ]);
  config.username = username;
  config.password = password;
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

Answer (score 0):

The sequelize model definition is really just a plain object so that can be set early. Model initialisation does require a `sequelize` instance to be passed in.

The setup was a bit clearer to me when using ES6 class definitions for the models. `sequelize.define` is replaced with a call to [`Model.init`](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-init), and this can all be done in an async setup function.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const { Model } = Sequelize

class User extends Model {
  static get modelFields(){
    return {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      }
    }
  }
  static get modelOptions(){
    return {
      version: true,
    }
  }
  static init(sequelize){
    const options = { ...this.modelOptions, sequelize }
    return super.init(this.modelFields, options)
  }
  static associate(models) {
    this.hasMany(models.Task)
  }
}

module.exports = User
```

```
const User = require('./User')

class Database {
   async static setup(){
     const credentials = await getCredentials()
     this.sequelize = new Sequelize(credentials)
     User.init(this.sequelize)
     this.User = User
     // When you have multiple models to associate add:
     this.User.associate(this)
   }
}

module.exports = Database
```

Due to the async credentials requirement, the rest of your app will just need to cope with the delay until the DB is setup. If this is a koa/express app for example, you could delay the server `.listen()` until the `Database.setup()` promise has resolved.

Comment: But will I need to run that `setup()` method every time I need to access the db object?

Comment: I have the slight sensation that I would need to pass it down via app context

Comment: `Database.sequelize` or `User` can be used once the connection is setup.

Answer (score 0):

As this would have changed a lot of my code. I have ended up by creating a script in golang that gets my credential "asynchronously" before running my server.
I have use some code from this package: https://github.com/telia-oss/aws-env

And then pass my starting script as a command argument so I could "inherit" the environmental variables
`./getEnv exec -- node index.js`

Comment: I have this problem too. I wish sequelize had allowed us to pass in async way to write configurations. Knex allows this.